# How to change DataGridRow Color when while DataGridCell.IsEditing is true?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, datagridcell

How to change DataGridRow Color when while DataGridCell.IsEditing is true?

When user double click on the cell it highlights the text and unselect the whole row (i:e change the row color to transparent). Should only highlight what is selected at the time and when user lost focus after editing or moving away from the field then the row can again be highlighted depending upon which row the cursor is on.

```
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsEditing" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />                          
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkBlue" />    

//Change DataGridRow BackGroudCorlor to transparent.                           
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same using BeginningEdit event and CellEditEnding event of the datagrid. Refer below code.

```
 <StackPanel>            
        <DataGrid BeginningEdit="DataGrid_BeginningEdit" CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding" x:Name="dgr"></DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObservableCollection<person> lst = new ObservableCollection<person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            lst.Add(new person() { FirstName = "Test" + i, LastName = "Lst" + i });

        }
        dgr.ItemsSource = lst;

    }

    private void DataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
       e.Row.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, Brushes.Transparent);
    }

    private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Resources.Remove(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey);            
    }
}
```